# Download file in while loop C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to download a file to a directory on the users computer. I first remove all files I do not need, then I get the files to download from a file online which looks like this:

FolderName|FileName|DownloadLink

However it is only downloading the first file, and the loop is running forever.

```
class ModpackFileControl
{
    static string modpackDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "ImperialPVP");
    static string userDir = Properties.Settings.Default.userDir;

    public static void InstallUpdates()
    {
        //Delete Files
        ArrayList infoFiles = new ArrayList();
        infoFiles.Add("currentMods.txt");
        infoFiles.Add("previousMods.txt");
        infoFiles.Add("currentVersion.txt");
        infoFiles.Add("latestVersion.txt");
        infoFiles.Add("previousVersion.txt");
        infoFiles.Add("updateInfo.txt");          

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
        foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
        {
            if (!infoFiles.Contains(Convert.ToString(file)))
            {
                file.Delete();
            }

        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            dir.Delete(true);
        }

        //Download Files
        string modpackFilesText = Path.Combine(modpackDir, "modpackFiles.txt");

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/lqqvg2fdw9qb989/modpackFiles.txt?dl=0", modpackFilesText);

        StreamReader modpackFiles = File.OpenText(modpackFilesText);
        string line = modpackFiles.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            string[] files = line.Split('|');

            string folder = files[0];
            string file = files[1];
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(modpackDir, folder)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(modpackDir, folder));
            }

            string downloadPath = Path.Combine(modpackDir, folder, file);
            string link = files[2];
            webClient.DownloadFile(link, downloadPath);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you deleting files? What if you delete the user's own files?

Comment: It will not delete user's own files because the files I am deleting are in a specific directory. example C:/username/appdata/roaming/programname/files to delete

Comment: I need to delete all current files in that directory, because they might conflict with future files I am downloading.

Comment: You do `string line = modpackFiles.ReadLine();` and then `while (line != null)` but you never change `line` again inside the loop.

Comment: @IsaacAbrahamson But what if the user made the working directory somewhere else? Or can they not do that?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that lol. Thank you Blorgbeard.

Comment: Why would I need to make the working directory somewhere else when only the program edits it, not the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a condition `line != null` for your while loop, but `line` is only set before the loop starts.

You probably want something like this:

```
    string line = modpackFiles.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
     // your existing code here 
     line = modpackFiles.ReadLine();
    }
```